# How to generate big data volume to perform load test using JMeter?

Tags: oracle, groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

We need to perform load test using JMeter, but the test database has few records. As you know we need a dataset which is similar to the production dataset which is huge. But there is no option to get the large data volume. We are using Oracle as database.
Does there any option in JMeter to simulate the large data volume?
What are the options do we have to perform a load test to meet the above criteria?

Comment: Can you create a copy of the production dataset to your test database? Also, is your test database similar in terms of performance to production? If not, your load test results may be hard to interpret/extrapolate.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a database dump, if necessary anonymize it removing the sensitive data and import it into your "empty" database, see [Moving Data Using Data Pump and Export/Import](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28300/expimp.htm#UPGRD008) for more details
2. If point it is not achievable for any reason you can use JMeter's [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler to directly add some fake data into the database using [INSERT Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems025.htm)
3. If point 2 cannot be implemented as well there are [some aspects which you still can test against a scaled-down environment](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-scaled-down-environment-part-two-five-things-you-can-test) like:

   - system(s) integration under the load
   - load allocation
   - monitoring the backend using [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools)
   - running a [soak test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing)